Expo app crashing on opening with Exception in HostObject::get for prop 'Qualities':
I have a RN expo app that properly runs on emulator but crashes with this stacktrace on production
FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
Process: com.myguardian.app, PID: 29951
com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Error: Exception in HostObject::get for prop 'Qualities': expo.modules.kotlin.exception.MissingTypeConverter: Cannot find type converter for 'expo.modules.core.arguments.ReadableArguments'., js engine: hermes, stack:
anonymous@1:3182954
loadModuleImplementation@1:97799
guardedLoadModule@1:97353
metroRequire@1:96981
anonymous@1:3179665
loadModuleImplementation@1:97799
guardedLoadModule@1:97353
metroRequire@1:96981
anonymous@1:3175245
loadModuleImplementation@1:97799
guardedLoadModule@1:97353
metroRequire@1:96981
anonymous@1:3168200
loadModuleImplementation@1:97799
guardedLoadModule@1:97353
metroRequire@1:96981
anonymous@1:3166625
loadModuleImplementation@1:97799
guardedLoadModule@1:97353
metroRequire@1:96981
anonymous@1:3165233
loadModuleImplementation@1:97799
guardedLoadModule@1:97353
metroRequire@1:96981
anonymous@1:3161614
loadModuleImplementation@1:97799
guardedLoadModule@1:97353
metroRequire@1:96981
anonymous@1:3157154
loadModuleImplementation@1:97799
guardedLoadModule@1:97353
metroRequire@1:96981
anonymous@1:3071729
loadModuleImplementation@1:97799
guardedLoadModule@1:97353
metroRequire@1:96981
anonymous@1:1130891
loadModuleImplementation@1:97799
guardedLoadModule@1:97353
metroRequire@1:96981
anonymous@1:1129983
loadModuleImplementation@1:97799
guardedLoadModule@1:97353
metroRequire@1:96981
anonymous@1:852638
loadModuleImplementation@1:97799
guardedLoadModule@1:97353
metroRequire@1:96981
anonymous@1:843327
loadModuleImplementation@1:97799
guardedLoadModule@1:97353
metroRequire@1:96981
anonymous@1:731666
loadModuleImplementation@1:97799
guardedLoadModule@1:97353
metroRequire@1:96981
anonymous@1:104178
loadModuleImplementation@1:97799
guardedLoadModule@1:97310
metroRequire@1:96981
global@1:96537
                                                                                                    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:65)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
                                                                                                    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:188)
                                                                                                    at com.facebook.jni.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                                                                                                    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:228)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

Tried to remove react-native-animated but still it crashed

I finally found a solution. I was using an expo-av library version that wasn't compatible with my expo version (SDK).
Steps

Run npx expo install --fix to see which dependencies aren't compatible with your current SDK version.
Make the suggested corrections in package.json or allow expo to fix for you.

